# Mongos count items not real?

Tags: mongodb, count, find, sharding, replicaset

I have a strange behavior of count() function in a mongos instance.
More than one hour ago I updated about 8.000 items in posts collection because I needed to convert tags objects to Array.

Now, when I query mongos with:

```
mongos> db.posts.find({blog: 'blog1', tags: {$type: 3}}).count()
4139
mongos> db.posts.findOne({blog: 'blog1', tags: {$type: 3}})
null
```

Why count() shows 4139 items and findOne returns a null value, even if RS are synchronized ?

**EDIT:**
There are 4 RS (all synchronized). 
I also did the same count query on all PRIMARIES and the result is always 0.
Only if I count on mongos the result is 4139!

Comment: Does it work if you use db.posts.find({blog: 'blog1', tags: {$type: 3}}).limit(1)? Can you show a document?

Comment: Null result also with limit(1):

mongos> db.posts.find({blog: 'blog1', tags: {$type: 3}}).limit(1)
null

Comment: @Ligio could you compare two count values one from db.post.stats() and one from your first query?

Comment: @Alex P: I think the collection stats() function will return stats from the entire data set, and not only filtered value. So, the count values from stats is not helpful, isn't it?

Comment: Can you show us a sh.status()?

Comment: @Ligio, yes I was thinking there is a some correlation between two. But after reading your update (i.e. mongos itself is the only issue), I guess it is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

`count()` takes corresponding value from metadata field `count` and on a sharded environment can show wrong value (there is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645)). It may count chunks which are currently moved by the balancer. I assume that you have more than one shard.

I would not really rely on `count` on environment with shards and use simple M/R script instead (try to see it with M/R by the way) until above mentioned bug will be fixed (2.5?). You can also take a look at my question regarding count - [db.collection.count() returns a lot more documents for sharded collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557696/db-collection-count-returns-a-lot-more-documents-for-sharded-collection-in-mon)

Comment: this particular count shouldn't take from metadata, that bug applies to no filter, when it counts all rows on the collection.

Comment: As far as I understand the filter condition is always false, so I guess it tries to run it on the entire collection.

Comment: Hmm the English is a bit vague but count will only ever get from meta data when there is no find condition as such I believe he means no filter in the `count()` function, i.e. `count({a:1})`

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, this bug can be unrelated in this case. I wonder what is the `count` value in `stats()` for this collection. Will delete my answer then.

Comment: Don't delete it, I think the chunk mgiration might be connected just not the full cause. I would have to perform some tests to find out why the count is so bad, it might relate to a bug in count optimisations recently that might mean it doesn't completely count the actual rows anymore

Answer (score -1):

If count() and limit() are acting weird, maybe your best shot is trying to repair the database. Go into the Mongo Shell and enter the following command:

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

For further explanations you can check the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/).